# In practice, should Contexts (Entity Framework) be used in controllers or in another layer of abstraction?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm currently learning .Net MVC with C#. I'm very curious as to how people use their Entity Framework contexts. Several related questions are listed below. I hope you can provide feedback.

1. Should contexts be instantiated in controllers? In models? In another layer of abstraction altogether? What would be the proper encapsulation?
2. When doing simple CRUD operations, should the call to say context.Add(entity) be called in the controller?
3. When creating queries to the context, should these queries be done in the controller? Or in the model? Should these use static methods if used in the model?

I hope my questions are quite clear. In general I'm interested how one should interact with a database, and how to abstract that properly from the application. Any info or advice related to that is welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All depends on size of your application. But for large applications you usually do not instantiate any dependencies in controllers. It makes your code [tightly coupled](http://www.math-cs.gordon.edu/courses/cps122/lectures-2013/Cohesion%20and%20Coupling.pdf) to some specific data access provider implementation. What if you will move to [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) tomorrow? Think about which places you will need to change in your application.

Same relates to mocks of data access provider when you do unit testing of controllers. You should be able to switch real object, which does persistence in your application, with some mocked implementation. That will be impossible (or at least very hard) if you will make your controllers depend on context and if you will instantiate context in controllers.

Traditional approach is following:

- Create data access abstraction, which your controllers will depend on. Usually [repositories](http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2012/02/22/The-Repository-Pattern-Explained.aspx) are such abstraction.
- And inject implementation of this abstraction into controller with some [dependency injection framework](http://www.ninject.org/).

Thus your controller will know only about abstraction, it will be easy to change data access provider (just create repository for MongoDB and give that implementation to controller) also it will be easy to give mocked implementation of data access provider, when you do unit testing of controllers.

Sample:

```
public class SalesController : Controller
{
    private IOrderRepository _repository; // depend on interface

    // inject some implementation of dependency into controller
    public SalesController(IOrderRepository repository)
    {
       _repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var orders = _repository.FindAll();
        return View(orders);
    }
}
```

The only place where you will use concrete repository implementation, is configuration of dependency injection framework, it's very easy to change implementation:

```
Bind<DbContext>().To<ShopEntities>();
Bind<IOrderRepository>().To<EFOrderRepository>();
```

Also it's very easy to do unit [testing](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart):

```
[Test]
public void ShoulReturnAllOrders()
{
    List<Order> orders = CreateListOfOrders();
    var mock = new Mock<IOrderRepository>();
    mock.Setup(r => r.FindAll()).Returns(orders);

    var controller = new SalesController(mock.Object);
    var result = (ViewResult)controller.Index();

    mock.VerifyAll();
    Assert.That(result.Model, Is.EqualTo(orders));
}
```

Comment: Finally one answer that talks about repository pattern & unit tests. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer. I find it rather helpful and interesting.

Comment: "What if you will move to MongoDB tomorrow?" This is well intentioned, but it's a pipe dream. You cannot even simply move from one relational database to another without significant development impact, forget about moving from relational to nosql or something else. You are better off building support for things that will actually change. In our case, it's our client's requirements, which most often translates to changes in the logical model. KISS & YAGNI

Answer (score 1):

This is a subject I stubmled not long ago. In the end, i think that doing those kind of stuff in separete layer is much better.

1. We create the context in the controller, and then pass it to the other layers, that controller use.
2. In the most simple scenario, someone could say that if you only add the entity then it's ok. But what if you have some kind of validation? I don't mean the field values, rahter sometihng like- You can't add new user, if the username already is taken. If you put the context.Add(entity) method in the controller, then soon you will see controller methods with 100+ lines of code, that do the logic, validation and so on.
3. Since our queries are quite complex, we have the "Queries" namespace that contain one class per query. This is described [here](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/10/08/favor-query-objects-over-repositories/). I don't quite understand your question with the static methods.

You have to remember, that all code that will be in the controllers will be harder to unit test- you have to set up some context and so on. In my opionion the "Thin controller, thich model" pattern is a must have for everything other than a showcase app in the ASP.NET MVC.

Also, it all depends what is your "Model" layer. Are you using ViewModels, or Models encapsulating all of your logic?

Comment: "create the context in the controller, and then pass it to the other layers, that controller use" - I don't think that this is a good idea. DbContexts are not thread safe...

Comment: @VladimirGondarev I agree, that's its not the best approach, but it works for us. About the thread safty.. Does it matter? Isn't there a new controller per request?

Comment: well, the thing is that Context creation is very fast operation. It makes no sense to pass it through.

Comment: In our case, there are few layers that use the context- we want all of them to use the same instance.

Comment: The question is, why? There is no reasonable explanation... No pros, only cons.

Answer (score 1):

To get a proper level of abstraction, you have to define an interface. For Instance:
**IDataBaseService** where all required operation are defined.
Such as: hm..

```
IEnumerable<BugItem> ReadAllBugs();
IEnumerable<BugItem> ReadAllBugsForProject(string project name);
```

etc...

Then, you can use any ioc container, to inject the implementation of IDataBaseService at runtime.

and controllers will use the IDataBaseService interface instead of DB Context.

PS: Sometimes such level of abstraction is a bit overkill.
It depends on a app.

1. it's ok to use a IDataBaseService in controllers.
2. see previous. there will be no such calls. You have to define a UpdateBugItemForProject
   method in your interface.
3. same as previous